# Angular mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

Please tell me if it is possible to resize the columns in mat-table.
I am using mat-table for displaying my data, column width is fixed as of now.
Please tell me if it is possible to make my columns resizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not implemented by the angular core team.

There's an open issue for this feature:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8312

You can find some community solution/workaraound:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtfc5v

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The mat-table assigns a class to each column that can be used to style it. In your styles.css:

```
.mat-column-columnName {
 flex: 0 0 10%
}
```

I use this trick to change width. I hope it works for you